# React Native - How to add two different half backgroundColor to <Text></Text>

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox, background, styles

**React Native**- How to add two different half `backgroundColor` to **`<Text></Text>`** as given in the image. For example like (*black height 50%, white height 50%*).
The content should be `adaptive width`.

```
<Text style={styles.inputLabel}>Lorem ipsum dolor sit am</Text>
```

[image]

Is this posible to create design in react native.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like below, have a View wrap with another view with absolute position which would have 50% height with a background color.

```
  <View>
      <View style={{position:'absolute'}}>
        <View style={{height:'50%',backgroundColor:'black',width:'100%',position:'absolute'}}/>
        <Text style={{color:'red',zIndex:1000}}>Some text here 12213 1312  223</Text>
        </View>
  </View>
```

[image]

Comment: I need adaptive width, this solution has not aplicable. because content has changed every block to dynamicly.

Comment: Not a multiple line, height is fixed. width is adaptive. Some times will get 2 words, sometimes 3 or 4 words. we can't able to set fixed width. As of your design is View background color full of page, i need content based background Color.

Comment: Updated the answer check the code now

Comment: It's not working, because we have set `width: '100%'`, so the background Color get full of page. also alignSelf not working this time....

Comment: Sorry I was testing on a snack

Comment: @tamilselvancst updated the answer, checked in Android